# What does having more than 1 font in CSS mean?

Tags: css

```
font:0.5em Georgia,"Times New Roman",Sans-Serif;
```

What does this mean when someone sets 3 different fonts? Also what is the `em` mean?

**Update:** Does the double quotations around Times New Roman mean it is telling CSS to use this first?

Comment: the double quotes are there because the name has spaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple fonts indicate an order of preference in fonts to use.  In this case, `Georgia` is the preferred font; if that's not available, use `Times New Roman`, and finally fall back to `Sans-Serif`.

[`em` is a relative measure of font size](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp), so in this case it means use half of the "normal" font size.

Comment: Sans-Serif is a family of fonts, not a single font.

Comment: Actually, em has a specific meaning. One "em" is the width of a capital M in the font and size specified.

Comment: While one could say a font is "available" or "installed" if it can fulfill its design function, the failover feature of css fonts is as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) describes "font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an available font does not have a glyph that can display a character needed, the later available fonts are tried."

Answer (score 2):

Failover. If you dont have the first one, it tries the second, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The first *installed* font is used, so, in your case, the font Georgia is used if installed. If not, Times New Roman is used. If neither of these are installed, then any Sans-Serif font will be used. (Yes, Sans-Serif is not the name of a particular font, but a name for a family of similar fonts, without so-called [serifs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif).)

When it comes to the unit "em", please see [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives in case of a font isn't installed on the system (if there's no Georgia, go for Times New Roman, ..).

`Em` is a CSS size unit (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp). It's equal to the text size (i.E. browser default, depends on context of course).

Answer (score 1):

If a font name contains white-space, it should be quoted. Single quotes must be used when using the inline "style" attribute in HTML